# \lstinputlisting with source file containing logic symbols

Tags: listings, input-encodings

I have a source code file that I want to include in my LaTeX document with `\lstinputlisting`. However, this source file contains logic symbols like `∃` (it's encoded in UTF-8), which produce errors. I tried using [listingsutf8](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listingsutf8), but it requires that the input file be encodable in an 8-bit fixed-width encoding, and as far as I know, no such encoding in existence supports logic symbols.

I've seen some similar questions on this site but they all seemed to deal exclusively with characters representable in Latin-1/ISO-8859-1.

LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting{test.txt}
\end{document}
```

test.txt:

```
~∃x. S(x) = 0
```

Error message:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined
(inputenc)                in inputencoding `latin1'.
```

Is there any way around this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. I guess you are using LaTeX or pdfLaTeX? Maybe XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX would be easier?

Comment: Sorry; I'm very new to LaTeX and hadn't been sure what to do. Added a minimal example. I'm using pdfLaTeX.

Comment: Ok, so it turns out the solution actually _isn't_ different from the existing questions, so I went ahead and flagged it as a duplicate.